How can I add a calendar as a column/field to a view table?
I need to add another calendar to the current view table. The table already includes a column for month and year, but some months have no transactions, so they don't show up in the table. I want to create a new calendar field to display monthly sales, regardless of whether there are any transactions. How would I do this?
Sample script:
select  T.MONTH_YEAR,
        ROUND(SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT),3) AS CURRENT_GROSS_AMOUNT,
        lag(ROUND(SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT),3)) over (partition by T.MATERIAL order by min(T.MONTH_YEAR)) as PREV_GROSS_AMOUNT
from transactions T

Here's the output:



MONTH_YEAR
CURRENT_GROSS_AMOUNT
PREV_GROSS_AMOUNT




Jan 2024
200



Feb 2024
200
200


Mar 2024
300
200


Apr 2024
400
300


Jul 2024
500
400


Aug 2024
600
500




The final script should be something like this:
select  T.MONTH_YEAR,
        /*add another calendar to display 2 months no display */
        ROUND(SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT),3) AS CURRENT_GROSS_AMOUNT,
        lag(ROUND(SUM(T.GROSS_AMOUNT),3)) over (partition by T.MATERIAL  order by min(T.MONTH_YEAR)) as PREV_GROSS_AMOUNT
from transactions T

Which would output:



MONTH_YEAR
calendar date
CURRENT_GROSS_AMOUNT
PREV_GROSS_AMOUNT




Jan 2024
Jan 2024
200



Feb 2024
Feb 2024
200
200


Mar 2024
Mar 2024
300
200


Apr 2024
Apr 2024
400
300



May 2024
0
400



Jun 2024
0
0


Jul 2024
Jul 2024
500
0


Aug 2024
Aug 2024
600
500




All you need is :
FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2024-01-01', '2024-12-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS month_date



Step 1: Create a calendar table [ you can change the date range as per your need]. This is the part which you basically need in your code the rest you can change as you wish.

Step 2: Aggregate transaction data by month (what you have done so far)

Step 3: Left Join the calendar with transaction data, this will join the data together and still show the calendar dates which are not being used for any transaction



WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT
    FORMAT_DATE('%b %Y', month_date) AS month_year,
    month_date
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2024-01-01', '2024-12-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS month_date
),


transaction_data AS (
  SELECT
    FORMAT_DATE('%b %Y', PARSE_DATE('%b %Y', T.month_year)) AS month_year,
    ROUND(SUM(T.gross_amount), 3) AS current_gross_amount
  FROM
    transactions T
  GROUP BY
    month_year
)

SELECT
  c.month_year,
  IFNULL(td.current_gross_amount, 0) AS current_gross_amount,
  LAG(IFNULL(td.current_gross_amount, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY c.month_date) AS prev_gross_amount
FROM
  calendar c
LEFT JOIN
  transaction_data td
ON
  c.month_year = td.month_year
ORDER BY
  c.month_date



Hi noted on this I've made a note of this. I genuinely appreciate the detailed script you've shared. Thank you so much.

"Hey @trillion, I'm trying to add another field CODE to the TRANSACTION table, but I'm not getting the desired output. Is it possible to add another field to the TRANSACTION table to achieve what I want?"
Script:
transaction_data AS (
SELECT code,    FORMAT_DATE('%b %Y', PARSE_DATE('%b %Y', T.month_year)) AS month_year,    ROUND(SUM(T.gross_amount), 3) AS current_gross_amount
FROM
transactions T
GROUP BY    month_year ,code
